Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference
i have been encountering this error while trying to run a machine running model, the model is supposed to power a driver drowsiness detection project
W0000 00:00:1715924294.765512    2256 inference_feedback_manager.cc:114] 
Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference. 
Disabling support for feedback tensors.

the model architecture is as follows:
#**MODEL**
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# the input shape is the desired size of the image 145 x 145 with 3 bytes color

#This is the first convolution
   model.add(Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(MaxPooling2D())
   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

# The second convolution
   model.add(Conv2D(32, 5, activation='relu'))
   model.add(BatchNormalization())
   model.add(MaxPooling2D())
   tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

# The third convolution
  model.add(Conv2D(64, 10, activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())
  model.add(MaxPooling2D())
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)

# The fourth convolution
  model.add(Conv2D(128, 12, activation='relu'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization())

# Flatten the results to feed into a DNN
  model.add(Flatten())
  model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
  model.add(Dropout(0.25))
  model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Only 1 output neuron.
  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"], optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))
  history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_data=test_generator)

# Defining the serving signature
  input_signature = [
      tf.TensorSpec(shape=[None, 145, 145, 3], dtype=tf.float32, name='input_tensor')
  ]

@tf.function(input_signature=input_signature)
def serving_fn(inputs):
    return model(inputs)

export_dir = 'E:\system project\project'  
tf.saved_model.save(serving_fn, export_dir)

# Loading the model for inference
loaded_model = tf.saved_model.load('my_model.keras')


I have this issue also

Same issue here too. So far, no solution was provided.

Same issues i'm facing.

After checking the mediapipe repo, it appears that they are changing the code base, and this is an issue in the latest mediapipe release.
So the better solution is to downgrade your mediapipe version.
Use this version : mediapipe==0.10.9
pip uninstall mediapipe #do this to uninstall your current version
pip install mediapipe==0.10.9

