Python Mediapipe "nonetype object has no landmark attribute" error with camera
Hello I am using the code from here https://learnopencv.com/building-a-body-posture-analysis-system-using-mediapipe/ For posture detection when a person is sitting
If I use the sample input.mp4 that was given I will get the error:
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
W0000 00:00:1717494251.025984   75032 inference_feedback_manager.cc:114] Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference. Disabling support for feedback tensors.
W0000 00:00:1717494251.048379   71780 inference_feedback_manager.cc:114] Feedback manager requires a model with a single signature inference. Disabling support for feedback tensors.

If I use my camera I get an extra error at the bottom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kanon\Desktop\Posture-analysis-system-using-MediaPipe-Pose\human_posture_analysis_video.py", line 97, in <module>
    l_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * w)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'landmark'

Thank you in advance for the help.
import cv2
import time
import math as m
import mediapipe as mp


# Calculate distance
def findDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    dist = m.sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    return dist


# Calculate angle.
def findAngle(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    theta = m.acos((y2 - y1) * (-y1) / (m.sqrt(
        (x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2) * y1))
    degree = int(180 / m.pi) * theta
    return degree


"""
Function to send alert. Use this function to send alert when bad posture detected.
Feel free to get creative and customize as per your convenience.
"""


def sendWarning(x):
    pass


# =============================CONSTANTS and INITIALIZATIONS=====================================#
# Initilize frame counters.
good_frames = 0
bad_frames = 0

# Font type.
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Colors.
blue = (255, 127, 0)
red = (50, 50, 255)
green = (127, 255, 0)
dark_blue = (127, 20, 0)
light_green = (127, 233, 100)
yellow = (0, 255, 255)
pink = (255, 0, 255)

# Initialize mediapipe pose class.
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mp_pose.Pose()
# ===============================================================================================#


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # For webcam input replace file name with 0.
    file_name = 'input.mp4'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    

    # Meta.
    fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
    width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
    height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
    frame_size = (width, height)
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

    # Video writer.
    video_output = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', fourcc, fps, frame_size)

    while cap.isOpened():
        # Capture frames.
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Null.Frames")
            break
        # Get fps.
        fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
        # Get height and width.
        h, w = image.shape[:2]

        # Convert the BGR image to RGB.
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Process the image.
        keypoints = pose.process(image)

        # Convert the image back to BGR.
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        # Use lm and lmPose as representative of the following methods.
        lm = keypoints.pose_landmarks
        lmPose = mp_pose.PoseLandmark

        # Acquire the landmark coordinates.
        # Once aligned properly, left or right should not be a concern.      
        # Left shoulder.
        l_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * w)
        l_shldr_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].y * h)
        # Right shoulder
        r_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.RIGHT_SHOULDER].x * w)
        r_shldr_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.RIGHT_SHOULDER].y * h)
        # Left ear.
        l_ear_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_EAR].x * w)
        l_ear_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_EAR].y * h)
        # Left hip.
        l_hip_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_HIP].x * w)
        l_hip_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_HIP].y * h)

        # Calculate distance between left shoulder and right shoulder points.
        offset = findDistance(l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y, r_shldr_x, r_shldr_y)

        # Assist to align the camera to point at the side view of the person.
        # Offset threshold 30 is based on results obtained from analysis over 100 samples.
        if offset < 100:
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(offset)) + ' Aligned', (w - 150, 30), font, 0.9, green, 2)
        else:
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(offset)) + ' Not Aligned', (w - 150, 30), font, 0.9, red, 2)

        # Calculate angles.
        neck_inclination = findAngle(l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y, l_ear_x, l_ear_y)
        torso_inclination = findAngle(l_hip_x, l_hip_y, l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y)

        # Draw landmarks.
        cv2.circle(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), 7, yellow, -1)
        cv2.circle(image, (l_ear_x, l_ear_y), 7, yellow, -1)

        # Let's take y - coordinate of P3 100px above x1,  for display elegance.
        # Although we are taking y = 0 while calculating angle between P1,P2,P3.
        cv2.circle(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y - 100), 7, yellow, -1)
        cv2.circle(image, (r_shldr_x, r_shldr_y), 7, pink, -1)
        cv2.circle(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y), 7, yellow, -1)

        # Similarly, here we are taking y - coordinate 100px above x1. Note that
        # you can take any value for y, not necessarily 100 or 200 pixels.
        cv2.circle(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y - 100), 7, yellow, -1)

        # Put text, Posture and angle inclination.
        # Text string for display.
        angle_text_string = 'Neck : ' + str(int(neck_inclination)) + '  Torso : ' + str(int(torso_inclination))

        # Determine whether good posture or bad posture.
        # The threshold angles have been set based on intuition.
        if neck_inclination < 40 and torso_inclination < 10:
            bad_frames = 0
            good_frames += 1
            
            cv2.putText(image, angle_text_string, (10, 30), font, 0.9, light_green, 2)
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(neck_inclination)), (l_shldr_x + 10, l_shldr_y), font, 0.9, light_green, 2)
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(torso_inclination)), (l_hip_x + 10, l_hip_y), font, 0.9, light_green, 2)

            # Join landmarks.
            cv2.line(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), (l_ear_x, l_ear_y), green, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y - 100), green, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y), (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), green, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y), (l_hip_x, l_hip_y - 100), green, 4)

        else:
            good_frames = 0
            bad_frames += 1

            cv2.putText(image, angle_text_string, (10, 30), font, 0.9, red, 2)
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(neck_inclination)), (l_shldr_x + 10, l_shldr_y), font, 0.9, red, 2)
            cv2.putText(image, str(int(torso_inclination)), (l_hip_x + 10, l_hip_y), font, 0.9, red, 2)

            # Join landmarks.
            cv2.line(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), (l_ear_x, l_ear_y), red, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y - 100), red, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y), (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), red, 4)
            cv2.line(image, (l_hip_x, l_hip_y), (l_hip_x, l_hip_y - 100), red, 4)

        # Calculate the time of remaining in a particular posture.
        good_time = (1 / fps) * good_frames
        bad_time =  (1 / fps) * bad_frames

        # Pose time.
        if good_time > 0:
            time_string_good = 'Good Posture Time : ' + str(round(good_time, 1)) + 's'
            cv2.putText(image, time_string_good, (10, h - 20), font, 0.9, green, 2)
        else:
            time_string_bad = 'Bad Posture Time : ' + str(round(bad_time, 1)) + 's'
            cv2.putText(image, time_string_bad, (10, h - 20), font, 0.9, red, 2)

        # If you stay in bad posture for more than 3 minutes (180s) send an alert.
        if bad_time > 180:
            sendWarning()
        # Write frames.
        video_output.write(image)

        # Display.
        cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Pose', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


Any help would be appreciated. I am new to Python but I'm trying to understand it line by line. I did test my camera with different code and it worked fine with this
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 
while(True): 
      
    ret, frame = vid.read() 
   
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame) 

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): 
        break

vid.release() 

cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please focus on one issue in your question. What is your main point? The warnings or the error with your camera?

Similar question regarding the warnings: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78493742/18667225

Regarding camera: Check lm and lmPose before you continue to access their attributes to make your software more robust against any image that might be caught by the camera. If you are using a live cam there may be frames that don't contain valid pose data.

@Markus I get all the warnings and the errors if I use the camera so both? I've just looked into the other similar question but there were no answer or comment.
I made a mistake that I forgot to add to the full error it was
"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\myuser\Desktop\folder\human_posture_analysis_video.py", line 97, in 
l_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * w)
^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'landmark'" I assume this means the camera did not detect my left shoulder?

but my posture should be lateral/ profile/ side view it makes sense that the camera won't see my left shoulder... I've tested with me facing front to the camera and it is still giving me the error

Does this answer your question? Mediapipe Display Body Landmarks Only

Let me try to explain my point. I have simplified your code for debugging purposes and added the check for lm and lmPose:
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp


# Initialize mediapipe pose class.
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mp_pose.Pose()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    
    while cap.isOpened():
        # Capture frames.
        success, image = cap.read()
        if not success:
            print("Null.Frames")
            break

        # Get height and width.
        h, w = image.shape[:2]

        # Convert the BGR image to RGB.
        imageRGB = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        # Process the image.
        keypoints = pose.process(imageRGB)

        # Use lm and lmPose as representative of the following methods.
        lm = keypoints.pose_landmarks
        lmPose = mp_pose.PoseLandmark

        if lm and lmPose:
            # Acquire the landmark coordinates.
    
            # Left shoulder.
            l_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].x * w)
            l_shldr_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.LEFT_SHOULDER].y * h)
            # Right shoulder
            r_shldr_x = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.RIGHT_SHOULDER].x * w)
            r_shldr_y = int(lm.landmark[lmPose.RIGHT_SHOULDER].y * h)
 
            # Draw landmarks.
            cv2.circle(image, (l_shldr_x, l_shldr_y), 7, (0, 255, 255), -1)
            cv2.circle(image, (r_shldr_x, r_shldr_y), 7, (255, 0, 255), -1)
        else:
            print("No landmarks found, please check if someone is in focus of camera!")

        # Display.
        cv2.imshow('MediaPipe Pose', image)
        if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

This code finds my shoulders pretty well. And if no person is in the scene it prints the message that I have put into the else-branch "No landmarks found, please check if someone is in focus of camera!".
The warnings are the same on my system. This is another question. But the landmark detection is working.
Please check on your system!
